# AoC day 8 issue (Java)

Tags: java

I was trying to solve a programming Christmas problem which you can read here: [advent of code day 8](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/8)

I used Java to solve this problem so I have the following function where `list` contain one action of the input file per index:

```
public int calculate_P1() {
    boolean[] config = new boolean[list.size()];
    int acc=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        if (list.get(i).substring(0, 3).equals("nop")) {
            if (config[i] == true) break;
            config[i] = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (list.get(i).substring(0, 3).equals("acc")) {
            if (config[i] == true) break;
            config[i] = true;

            if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '+') acc += Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5));
            if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '-') acc -= Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5));
            continue;
        }

        if (list.get(i).substring(0, 3).equals("jmp")) {
            if (config[i] == true) break;
            config[i] = true;

            if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '+') i += (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5)));
            if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '-') i -= (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5)));

            i--;
        }
    }

    return acc;
}
```

This solves the example input correctly but, the input file is much longer and I get `261` as an output while it should be `1179`... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many elements are there in the input set?

Comment: What does `i--;` do at the end of the last if stmnt block?

Comment: @dbl it decrements i by 1 ;)

Comment: there are 631 elements in my input set @ParthManaktala

Comment: Also `i--;` decrements `i` by 1 on the `"jmp"` case because the `for` increases `i` value by 1 right after so it does not get off in the next iteration @dbl

Comment: I'm really lost as I don't see any issue in my code but thanks man :)

Comment: So decremetation was not the issue, yet it was somehow connected... changeing the whole body of the last if statement to `i += Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(4)) - 1;` resolve the issue and I get correct answer. GL with P2.

Comment: @dbl that was it, correct now! thanks a lot

Comment: I used the same approach for P1, even though my loop is twice as short from your snippet. For P2 I ended up with recursion :) My loop had two driver variables `i` & `step`, where `i` was modified by `i+=step`, and step was assingend accorfing to the first 3 letters - the instruction(or in my case the key from  Map<String, Integer> though). That's why i had no decrementation... So it was easy for me to go recursive (replacing `step` assingments with selfcalls). GL with P2.

Comment: I didn't use recursion in this case but a function that kept changing "nop" to "jmp" and calculating if it's an infinite loop or not till I got the answer, seemed easier for my programming level :P. Yesterday's bags problem definitely needed some recursion though! GL on the next problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is these two statements for `jmp`:

```
        if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '+') i += (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5)));
        if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '-') i -= (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5)));
```

If the statement is `jmp +443` (the first jump statement in my input) the first line already changes `i` and then the second `if` doesn't check the operand of the `jmp +443` statement anymore, it checks the operand of the jump target.

With my input the instruction at the first jump target is `acc -1`, which means that the second if-statement is evaluated too, meaning that the new `i` is calculated wrong.

A better solution is to use an `if / else if` combination:

```
        if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '+') 
            i += (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5)));
        else if (list.get(i).charAt(4) == '-') 
            i -= (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(5)));
```

The simplest solution however is to let `Integer.parseInt()` take care of the `+` and `-` sign:

```
        i += Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(4));
```

(this can also be applied to the "acc" case...)

Comment: Or just replace this entire if-else-if with `i += Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).substring(4));`. `parseInt` can parse '+' and '-' prefixes